# Blank mails problem in thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, mail, imap

I have configure gmail IMAP account in thunderbird (10.0.2) on UBUNTU 11.04.

All things was working fine, one day i found blank mails in my local sub folder which have filter to download mail from IMAP indox to local inbox. No subject no body no person name, nothing just a size i have that only 0.1k. And sometime when i try to drag and drop mails from IMAP to local, this happen without any notification. i move these mails from IMAP to local folder that means i never find these mail in IMAP account. So i just lost my mail.

My Question is that **why this happened**, i dont want **this will happen with again** and **how can i recover those blank mail** in thunderbird.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I do lot of googled and found something, but its not my answer that was i looking for it.

Some of expert say that happened following things.

1. Bad network connectivity during download mails.
2. Something messed up in .msf file (thunderbird folder file)
3. Something happened bad in applied filtered.
4. Bad compacting of local folder.

So i try all these things, i close my TB (ThunderBird), then remove .msf file and reopen TB. And Compact very local folder and Recreate my all filters.

That might be help full for those how applied filters in copy state. But i applied in move states. So that i lost my mails and there is no way to recover them.

If any one know about how to recover them, any suggestion welcome.

Comment: Please use the *Post answer* button only for actual answers. You should modify your original question to add additional information.